# Ветвление событий

Tags: c++, c

Есть задача, которая требует ветвления кода, я использовал машинное состояние `switch case` и `enum`.

Интересует какие еще есть хорошие варианты ветвления - например в моей задаче получилось 9 состояний. И можно ли такие вещи эффективно решать с помощью `if else`, или данный цикл подходит только для узких случаев.

Comment: Можно как угодно. Можно через switch. Можно через if/else. Можно даже через виртуальные функции.

Comment: Я понимаю что вариантов множество, вопрос в другом - если например у меня 10-50 ветвлений, что оптимальнее всего использовать что бы не загрязнять код и не делать лишнюю работу.

Comment: Что оптимальнее всего, это может вам сказать только профилирование. Чтобы не загрязнять код, я бы лично использовал `std::map<State, std::function<State (void)>>`, хотя это, возможно, не так эффективно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дать совершенно однозначный ответ невозможно - всегда есть масса факторов, учесть которые невозможно - вплоть до вкусовых предпочтений автора или стиля кодирования, принятого в этой команде.

`switch` - если он применим - пожалуй, будет поэффективнее, но опять же, если у него 50 `case`, то встает вопрос - не выбрать ли действительно `map` или иную структуру (скажем, если эти 50 значений - от 0 до 49, то так и просится массив/вектор) для выбора действия по значению.

Но могут быть ситуации, когда `switch` просто невозможно применить - простейший пример - для строк.

Но, откровенно говоря, при таком сильном ветвлении я бы задумался над вопросом - а правильно ли я спроектировал? нельзя ли обойтись без такого сильного ветвления вовсе?